# XML transformations, with the help of XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

and two files, which both have in each row, the value to be searched for, (file1) and the replacements file (file2),

which look like this

File 1:

```
  XML Developer's Guide
    Midnight Rain
...
```

and file2 (with the replacements):

```
self1. replacement title 1
self2. replacement title 2
...
```

I need a way with an xslt file, to

1. Replace all title elements, that match, with what follows the `.` and the space
2. Create a new element in the xml file `<hold>` that will have the info that is before the `.` and the space, so the result should look like the below

Output xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>replacement title 1</title>
      <hold>self1</hold>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>replacement title 2</title>
      <hold>self2</hold>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by assuming you have converted the parameter files into XML form as

```
<changes>
  <change id="self1" from="XML Developer's Guide" to="replacement title 1"/>
  <change id="self2" from="Midnight Rain" to="replacement title 2"/>
</changes>
```

and this XML is in global variable $changes.

You can now achieve the transformation with an identity template, plus the rule:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
   <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="$changes/change[@from=current()]"/>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$replacement">
       <title><xsl:value-of select="$replacement/@to"/></title>
       <hold><xsl:value-of select="$replacement/@id"/></hold>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

All that remains is to construct the XML representation of the parameter files:

```
<xsl:variable name="$replacements">
  <xsl:variable name="f1" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('file1.txt'), '\r?\n')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="f2" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('file2.txt'), '\r?\n')"/>
  <changes>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($f1)">
      <xsl:variable name="i" select="."/> 
      <change id="{substring-before($f2[$i], '.')}"
              from="{normalize-space($f1[$i])}"
              to="{normalize-space(substring-after($f2[$i], '.'))}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </changes>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: i would appreciate a full example in http://xsltransform.net/, if possible, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't provide a free coding service. I expect you to do some of the work yourself.